# If $G$ is finite and every subgroup is characteristic then $G$ is abelian and cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I've been trying to prove that if $G$ is finite and every subgroup is characteristic then $G$ is cyclic.
If I suppose that $G$ is abelian I've been able to prove it this way

The statement is true if $|G|=1$, so lets supose by induction that it is true for every group of order less than $n$.

Then if $|G|=n=p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots p_m^{\alpha_m}$ with $p_i$ primes, as $G$ is abelian, we know that is direct product of its uniques Sylow subgroups

$$G=P_1P_2 \cdots P_m$$

Let $K$ be a subgroup of $P_i$ and $f \in Aut(P_i)$, then we can define $h:G \longrightarrow G$ such that given $a \in G$ and $a=a_1 \cdots a_m$ its unique expresion as a product where $a_j \in P_j$,

$$h(a)=h(a_1\cdots a_m)=a_1 \cdots a_{i-1} f(a_i) a_{i+1} \cdots a_m$$

The function $h$ is a homomorphism because given $a, b \in G$, if we express $a=a_1 \cdots a_m$, $b=b_1 \cdots b_m$ in the unique way as specified before, we have that

$$ab=(a_1\cdots a_m)(b_1\cdots b_m)=(a_1b_1) \cdots (a_mb_m)$$

and again, because $a_jb_j \in P_j$, by uniqueness of the expresion we have

$$h(ab)=(a_1b_1) \cdots (a_{i-1}b_{i-1}) f(a_ib_i) (a_{i+1}b_{i+1}) \cdots (a_mb_m)=\\=(a_1b_1) \cdots (a_{i-1}b_{i-1}) f(a_i)f(b_i) (a_{i+1}b_{i+1}) \cdots (a_mb_m)=\\=(a_1 \cdots a_{i-1} f(a_i) a_{i+1} \cdots a_m)(b_1 \cdots b_{i-1} f(b_i) b_{i+1} \cdots b_m)=\\=h(a)h(b)$$

Furthermore, $h$ is inyective because if $h(a)=h(b)$ then

$$a_1 \cdots a_{i-1} f(a_i) a_{i+1} \cdots a_m=b_1 \cdots b_{i-1} f(b_i) b_{i+1} \cdots b_m$$

and again by uniqueness of the expression of an element of $G$ as a product of elements of $P_j$ we have that $a_j=b_j$ if $j=1, \cdots, i-1,i+1, \cdots m$ and $f(a_i)=f(b_i)$, and as $f$ is injective, $a_j=b_j$ and $a=b$.
We stated that $G$ is finite so $h$ is onto and we conclude that $h \in Aut(G)$.
Now, we observe that as $K \subset P_i$ and it is a characteristic group of $G$, $f(K)=h(K)=K$ so $K$ is a characteristic group of $P_i$.

So, we have proven that every subgroup of $P_i$ is characteristic in $P_i$ so by induction hypothesis, every $P_i$ is cyclic and there exists elements $a_1, \cdots, a_m$ in $G$ such that $o(a_i)=p_i^{\alpha_i}$.
Lastly, we observe that as the $\gcd(p_1^{\alpha_1}, \cdots, p_m^{\alpha_m})=1$ and $G$ is abelian, we conclude that

$$o(a_1\cdots a_m)=p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots p_m^{\alpha_m}=|G|$$

and then $G$ is cyclic.

My doubts now are if this prove is correct and, in case it is correct, is there a way to prove in an easy way that if $G$ is finite and every subgroup is characteristic then $G$ is abelian?

Thank you very much for the comments.

Comment: What if $G$ is a $p$-group? Then there's no smaller subgroup to use the induction hypothesis on.

Comment: Note that every finite abelian group $G$ is isomorphic to $$C_{n_1}\times C_{n_2}\times \ldots \times C_{n_k}$$ for some integers $k\geq 0$ and $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k\geq 2$ such that $n_1\mid n_2\mid\ldots\mid n_k$.  Here, $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$.  If $G$ is not cyclic, then $k\geq 2$.  Show that $G$ has an automorphism that does not fix a subgroup isomorphic to $C_{n_1}$.

Comment: @Matt Samuel You are right, I should say that since every abelian p-group is charateristically simple, in the factorization on the cardinal of G there must be at least two different primes. Do you think it would be correcto then?

Comment: Compare also with [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153007/if-g-is-finite-and-abelian-then-every-subgroup-of-g-is-characteristic-if-an?rq=1).

Comment: @Batominovsky I'm trying to prove it is true for every finite group, without knowing it is abelian. If I assume it is abelian, with the above correction I think my prove would also work. So the point is proving it without knowing it is abelian or proving that under the thesis that every subgroup is characteristic then the group must be abelian.

Comment: If the group is not abelian, then every subgroup is normal. But the finite groups for which every subgroup is normal are well known, and the nonabelian ones have a direct factor isomorphic to the quaternion group of order $8$. And that group does not satisfy the property that every subgroup is characteristic.

Comment: @Arturo That seems a bit like shooting a fly with a bazooka.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I was thinking about that too, but as Matt says, I was wondering if there was a more elementary way of getting the result because although the clasiffication of Dedekind groups is well known, the clasiffication theorem is not easy at all. Any more ideas?

Comment: @MattSamuel What's a gentle way of killing the fly in this particular case? I have thought a little about the problem and I don't see a direct proof. If you have one please share.

Answer (score 1):

**A partial answer:** I show that $Aut(G)$ must be abelian, in particular $Inn(G)$ is abelian, and so $G$ is of class at most $2$. Perhaps one can complete the result from that point.

Let $A=Aut(G)$ and $C_1,C_2,..., C_n$ be the all cyclic subgroups of $G$. By hypothesis, they are all $A$-invariant. Let $K_i$ be the kernel of the action $A$ on $C_i$.

Since $Aut(C_i)$ are abelian we see that $A/K_i$ are abelian. Notice that 
$$K=\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}K_i=1$$

as $K$ must act trivially on $G$. Since we can embed $A/K=A$ to the abelian group $$\prod_{i=1}^{n} A/K_i$$
 by sending $(aK)\to (aK_1,aK_2,...,aK_n)$, we see that $A=Aut(G)$ is abelian.

By using the fact that $Aut(G)$ is abelian, one can show that $[G,A]\leq Z(G)$ and $G'\leq C_G(A)$.